# Unable to find file path in getStaticProps function of internal page in Next Js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, react-intl

I am working on multi-language feature on Next JS app. Here is the folder structure of my project.

[image: Folder Structure of the app]

On the index page i.e. Home page, I am able to get the locales module using `getStaticProps` :

```
export function getStaticProps({ locale }) {
    return {
      props: {
        messages: require(`../locales/${locale}.json`),
      },
    };
}
```

But when I use this in `/settings/locations/index/js` it is showing error as follows:
[image]

I have tried with `messages: require('@/locales/${locale}.json')` and `messages: require('../../locales/${locale}.json')` both way.

Comment: Have you tried `require(\`../../../locales/${locale}.json\`)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should try with-

```js
 return {
    props: {
      messages: require(`../../../locales/${locale}.json`),
    },
 };
```

Comment: why it was not working with @/locales ? while I am including the navbar on the same page with `import NavBar from '@/components/NavBar'`

Comment: Because this is a JSON file. You can import JSON data like this. `@/components/NavBar` is a react component that's why its works.

Comment: navbar is a jsx component and locale is a json file